Trying to call ioctl BLKRRPART from Rust returns Bad Address os error 14
As a personal project I try to write project with no crates. I need to use syscall ioctl BLKRRPART to re-read partition table on a drive.
This is my current code:
const BLKRRPART: u64 = 0x00001269; // Request number or something.

extern "C" {
    fn ioctl(fd: RawFd, request: u64, ...) -> i32;
}

pub fn refresh_partition_table(drive_path: &str) -> Result<(), SpamErrors> {
    let dr = File::open(drive_path)?;
    let fd: RawFd = dr.as_raw_fd();
    // Here we GOOOO
    let syscall = unsafe { ioctl(fd, BLKRRPART) };
    if syscall == -1 {
        return Err(SpamErrors::IOErrors(io::Error::last_os_error().to_string()))
    }
    Ok(())
}


But when I try to run this, it returns Bad address (os error 14) and does not work.
I tried searching but I could not find a solution. I also tried to use BLKPG op instead but it returned Invalid argument so I assume I just used it wrongly.
I also tried to pass null pointer from std::ptr::null as an argument but it also did nothing.
Please give answers that do not recommend using some external crates. Thanks.
Edit:
I tried using crates for troubleshooting, did not work. But I tried in C, and interesting thing happened that when I declared similar thing as in rust, so #define BLKRRPART 0x00001269 it also did not work, resulting in ioctl(3, BLKPG, NULL)   = -1 EFAULT (Bad address) in strace in all the cases. But when I included <linux/fs.h> which includes BLKRRPART itself, it worked fine. It's weird cus I got this value from grepping it directly from fs.h.
This is the simplest working example:
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int main() {
  int fd = open("/dev/sdb", O_RDONLY);
  int res = ioctl(fd, BLKRRPART);
  printf("%d", res);
}

and this is example that does not work:
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BLKRRPART 0x00001269

int main() {
  int fd = open("/dev/sdb", O_RDONLY);
  int res = ioctl(fd, BLKRRPART);
  printf("%d", res);
}

And this is what comes out when greping the value of BLKRRPART:
sudo grep -r "BLKRR" /usr/include/linux                          
/usr/include/linux/fs.h:#define BLKRRPART  _IO(0x12,95) /* re-read partition table */


It would be useful to see the C code you're attempting to replicate

Are you absolutely sure your value for BLKRRPART is correct? Try printing it out at the start of main just to check.

BTW you should use the std::ffi typedefs such as c_int, c_ulong, etc instead of specifying the sized integer types. This keeps your code portable and avoids accidentally using the wrong signature.

@PitaJ Yeah while writing edit I realized that it just might be wrong, I checked and indeed it's wrong. Idk why I assumed it's gonna be that value. Well now I just have to find out how to get that value in Rust.

Using the nix crate, you can define a function that wraps your ioctl with nix::ioctl_none!(blkrrpart, 0x12, 95).
